# Understanding the Formula for Amperage with Copper

Tags: math, charge, copper

From the beginning of *Practical Electronics for Inventors*:

> [image]
> [image]

This makes sense to me up until the term $$1A = \left( \frac{1C}{1s} \right) \left( \frac{\text{electron}}{-1.602 \times 10^{-19} C} \right)$$ is introduced.

In particular, where does the

$$
\left( \frac{\text{electron}}{-1.602 \times 10^{-19} C} \right)
$$

term come from?

Comment: George, just look at the units. The Coulombs cross-cancel, leaving electrons/s. Which is what they set out to say. They should have written "1 electron" instead of just "electron," thought to make it clearer. Then you would realize that the second factor is just "1 electron" per "-1.602 x 10^-19 Coulomb". The first factor is just a restatement of what an amp is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the really nice things is that an amp (or ampere or \$1\:\text{A}\$) has the potential to be a mentally countable thing per unit time, just like when you may have been told about "5 apples moving by on a conveyor belt per second" in grade school. It is really easy to visualize, even for a child.

This is unlike an Ohm, which instead is the number of "joule-seconds" per "Coulomb-squared" and is a bit harder to visualize! (A Joule-second is a measure of angular momentum -- like with a spinning billiard ball, but how do you apply that to the square of something that feels 'countable' like Coulombs? There is a way, as an electron has something called *spin angular momentum* measured in Joule-seconds and with a value measured along any particular direction as \$\frac{\hbar}{2}\$. But... it's less easy to teach quantum mechanical approaches to understanding an Ohm, for sure.)

In this case, they start out by letting you know that there is some amount of charge (carried by electrons in this case) that can move past some point in a wire at a certain rate. But the definition of an amp doesn't tell you how many. Instead, the definition talks about how much charge moves past a point and that the ratio, Coulombs per second, is also known as an amp. But what if you want to know how many discretely countable units of charge that is?

Since the electron is the charge-carrier in this case, what you need to know is how many electrons make up a Coulomb. Or else, otherwise, you need to know how much of a Coulomb does one electron represent? Either way, you are good to go. But you need this ratio to help out.

It turns out that someone has figured this out and noticed that one electron is the same as about \$-1.602\times10^{-19}\:\text{C}\$. (The sign isn't there to confuse you. It's just there because humans have made the choice that (+) is the sign of charge for a proton and that (-) is the sign of the charge for an electron and it helps to keep that detail when one writes because it is more explicit and detailed that way.)

As \$1\:\text{A}=\frac{1 \:\text{C}}{1 \:\text{s}}\$ (definition) and as it turns out that an electron is \$1\:\text{electron} = -1.602\times10^{-19}\:\text{C}\$, then we can divide both sides by \$-1.602\times10^{-19}\:\text{C}\$ to find that:

$$1=\frac{1\:\text{electron}}{-1.602\times10^{-19}\:\text{C}}$$

Now, as you know, multiplying something by 1 doesn't change it. So we are just fine with the following application of dimensional analysis and math:

$$\begin{align*}
1\:\text{A}&=\frac{1 \:\text{C}}{1 \:\text{s}}
\\\\
&= \frac{1 \:\text{C}}{1 \:\text{s}}\cdot 1
\\\\
&= \frac{1 \:\text{C}}{1 \:\text{s}}\cdot \frac{1\:\text{electron}}{-1.602\times10^{-19}\:\text{C}}
\\\\
&= \frac{1 }{1 \:\text{s}}\cdot \frac{1\:\text{electron}}{-1.602\times10^{-19}}
\\\\
&= \frac{1 }{-1.602\times10^{-19}}\cdot \frac{\text{electron}}{\text{s}}
\\\\
&=-6.2422\times 10^{18}\: \frac{\text{electron}}{\text{s}}
\end{align*}$$

It's just another way of writing it. However, it now assumes that we are dealing with electrons and not protons, for example. The sign is retained to show we are talking about electron charges and not proton charges. For your own mental purposes, it's just fine dropping the sign if all you want to know is how many per second. Most of us do that, in fact, unless we feel there is some strong need to retain the sign.

Comment: Really blown away by all of the thorough answers to my (in retrospect really silly and dumb) beginner's question!  Thank you.

Comment: @George I think we all go through this. It's been a long time for me so I don't remember my own struggles as well as I wish. But that doesn't mean I didn't ask myself a similar question. I probably did. It's not silly or dumb. We all start somewhere and then work to go somewhere else. You are just fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the equations should look like this:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
Q &= &I \cdot t \\
I &=& \frac{Q}{t} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

For example:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
1 \mathrm{A} &=& \frac{1 \mathrm{C}}{1 \mathrm{s}} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The charge of an Electron:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
Q_{\mathrm{e}} &= & -1.602 \cdot 10^{-19} \mathrm{C} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Which means

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
1 \mathrm{C} &= & -\frac{Q_{\mathrm{e}}}{1.602 \cdot 10^{-19}} \\
 &=& - 6.242 \cdot 10^{18} Q_{\mathrm{e}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

This tells us how many electrons make up one Coulomb.
If we now insert this value in the equation above, we get:

\begin{eqnarray}
1 \mathrm{A} &=& \frac{1 \mathrm{C}}{1 \mathrm{s}} \\
1 \mathrm{A} &=& \frac{ - 6.242 \cdot 10^{18} \mathrm{electrons}}{1 \mathrm{s}} \\
\end{eqnarray}

And this is exactly what they wrote in the article.